# Multiplicar una columna del marco de datos en función de varias condiciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, condiciones

Me gustaria multiplicar una columna (o crear una nueva con los valores multiplicadas) basados sobre dos condiciones. Entonces intenté :

```
c1 = df['Mean']=='SEPA' and df['Engagement'] == 'M'
c2 = df['Mean']!='SEPA' and df['Engagement'] == 'M'
df.loc[c1, ['Amount Eq Euro']] *= 62
df.loc[c2, ['Amount Eq Euro']] *= 18
```

Aqui esta la dataframe

```
    Mean    Engagement  Amount Eq Euro
2   CB (PAYPAL) S   50.0
3   CB  S   50.0
4   CB  S   50.0
5   CB (PAYPAL) M   20.0
6   CB  S   75.0
... ... ... ...
6238    CB  S   30.0
6239    CB  S   80.0
6240    SEPA    M   10.0
6241    CB  S   100.0
6242    NaN M   10.0
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-bbd424e0088f> in <module>()
      3 #                                            df['Amount Eq Euro'] * 18)
      4 
----> 5 c1 = df['Mean']=='SEPA' and df['Engagement'] == 'M'
      6 c2 = df['Mean']!='SEPA' and df['Engagement'] == 'M'
      7 df.loc[c1, ['Amount Eq Euro']] *= 62

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
   1329         raise ValueError(
-> 1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1332         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: No puedes usar los operadores normales, en subñigar usa los operadores bitwise

Answer (score 1):

En las condiciones, sustituya `and` con `&` ("bitwise and"), y añada paréntesis:

```py
c1 = (df['Mean']=='SEPA') & (df['Engagement'] == 'M')
c2 = (df['Mean']!='SEPA') & (df['Engagement'] == 'M')
```

...

**Explicación:**

El operador `and` requiere una pareja de operandos que se puedan convertir en bool (True o False).
Pero en la definición de `c1`, los operandos `df['Mean']=='SEPA'` y `df['Engagement'] == 'M'` son de tipo `pandas.Series` y contienen múltiples valores True/False.
El ValueError explica que python no sabe cómo debería convertir una serie de valores True/False en un único valor True/False: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" (el valor True o False de una serie es ambiguo).
Y después propone maneras de producir un valor de True o False con una serie: "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()".
((( Por ejemplo `(df['Engagement']=='SEPA').all()` devuelve True si todos los elementos de la serie `df['Engagement']=='SEPA'` son True, y False si no. )))

Por otro lado, el operador `&` también funciona con una pareja de series (o listas o arrays) y opera sobre los elementos de las 2 series de uno en uno para cada índice.
Así,

```
c1 = (df['Mean']=='SEPA') & (df['Engagement']=='M')
```

produce una serie `c1` de modo que `c1.iloc[n]` sea igual a

```
df['Mean'].iloc[n]=='SEPA' and df['Engagement'].iloc[n]=='M'
```

para todos los índices `n`.

Espero que todo esté claro.

Comment: Se aplaude la intención de responder. Sin embargo, una respuesta con solo código es considerada de baja calidad. Te invito a leer [answer] y a [edit] tu respuesta para agregar una explicación, que puede ser breve, de por qué o cómo tu código resuelve el problema planteado en la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por su comentario. Edité mi respuesta.